# Screen Flicker after using Skype

Tags: 14.04, display, skype

Last week I got a new Asus Zenbook ux303ua, which I proceeded to install Ubuntu onto (my first time running Ubuntu or Linux). Everything has gone pretty smoothly over the last week however today I have started experiencing an issue after installing Skype from the Software Centre and proceeding to call someone with it.

The call audio was fine but the video had a blue box that would continuously flicker over the incoming video. After I ended the call, the area of screen where the Skype window was sitting started to flicker in a similar way (not blue this time however). I restarted the computer, and as soon as I logged back in, the flickering continued in the same spot. I even booted into my Windows partition and the flickering happens on there as well.

I have no idea what could be causing any of this and do not know what I can do in an attempt to resolve the issue. Any advice or guidance as to what I should do next or the causation of this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: I will be honest, but this sounds more of a hardware issue if it is happening in both Windows and Ubuntu. I doubt Ubuntu nor Skype is the cause - just a coincidence. I would recommend calling the store you bought it from or ASUS and ask for their advice to see if this is a common problem among that range. There could even be a recall if the same problem is occurring to many other people too.